How to customize Kubernetes CPU resources with Helm charts based on environment
I have my deployment.yaml and values.yaml files within the templates directory of Helm chart for the container I will be running using Helm.
Now I want to be able define and utilize environment variables for kubernetes cpu utilization for my pipeline so when the helm is ran, it can pick the right resource values based on the env(dev,test and prod). Dev and Test has less resources than production.
How do I pass this in and have helm grab the resources correctly when I use Helm to run the application?
Here is some part of my deployment.yaml file
# ...
   resources:
          limits:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            cpu: {{ .Values.resources.requests.cpu }}
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}
# ...

Here is some part of my values.yaml file
# ...
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 900m
    memory: 500Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 600m
    memory: 300Mi
# ...

How can I pull the cpu values from values.yaml based on the environment when I run helm?
Is this possible? If yes, then how do I do this?

You can use separate values files per environment with the desired resources defined:
values-dev.yaml
values-prod.yaml
values-test.yaml

Or you can create a condition in your templates:
{{ if .Values.prod }}
  # Do something
{{ else }}
  # Do something else
{{ end }}

Reference: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/

I tried to add the values in my values.yaml file as below resources:
nonprod:
    limits:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 300Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 400m
      memory: 200Mi
  prod:
    limits:
      cpu: 800m
      memory: 1000Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 800m
      memory: 1000Mi    

                                                                                                                                and tried to tweak the deployment.yaml as below but getting templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 42: mapping values are not allowed in this context. Having hard time to fix the spaces/indentations and so forth.   Any help on this is really helpful.              
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.metadata.name }}
  namespace:  {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}"
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.deployment.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.service.name}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.service.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 30
        resources:
  {{- if .Values.nonprod }}
  limits:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.limits.memory }}
  requests:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.nonprod.requests.memory }}
  {{else}}    
  limits:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.limits.memory }}
  requests:
      cpu: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.cpu }}
      memory: {{ .Values.resources.prod.requests.memory }}
  {{- end }}    
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /root/tls.crt
            name: config
            subPath: tls.crt
          - mountPath: /root/tls.key
            name: config
            subPath: tls.key
      volumes:
      - name: config
        secret:
          secretName: config
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: default-image-pull-secret
      

